# what to do with svn dump file?

Tags: svn

Without going into a lot of unnecessary details I was given what looks to me like an svn dump file. the name looks something like this foo_svn_09172014.dump. I have never used svn at all and the person who gave me the file is not a techie person. I opened it using vim to see what was inside and I see a lot of php code in it. about 25mb worth. So, now what? What do I do with it? I can imagine (ok more like hope for) that maybe there is a way to run some command line that will put everything nicely into my own computer. Note that all I have is a windows machine although I do have cygwin install. Please advice.

Comment: You probably can import that dump into a new SVN repository and do a checkout from that.

Comment: What you do with it depends on why you were given the file in the first place. What goal are you trying to accomplish with this file?

Comment: I want to look at the code to see if I can fix some errors and also make some modifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a subversion repository using [`svnadmin create`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.create.html). Then load the dump into the repository using [`svnadmin load`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.load.html).

Comment: This ended up solving the problem as far as being able to get all the code. Ofcourse, it merits to mention that I needed to install some software (tortoise svn in my case) in order to run the commands above.